# how to stop conditional rendering from flashing?

Tags: meteor, rendering, meteor-blaze

I'm not sure if this is a Meteor issue or a generic one but I have the following code in my app.

```
<template name='admin'>
<div class='admin container-fluid noPadding'>
    {{#if isInRole 'Admin'}}
        <h3 class="homepageText">Server Statistics</h3>
        {{> serverFacts}}
    {{else}}
        You don't belong here!
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

When the page renders I see "You don't belong here!", then "Server Statistics" replaces it a second or so later. I have the same problem other places in my app always with a Blaze `{{#if ...}}` involved. Is there a way to stop the page from displaying in the browser until the rendering has completed and settled down?

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic issue with reactive applications - rendering often happens while the data is still being pushed to the client. The normal solution is to use a spinner (ex: [sacha:spin](https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin)) until the underlying subscription(s) are ready. Then in Blaze you end up with:

```
<template name='admin'>
{{#if loading}}
  {{> spin}}
{{else}}
  <div class='admin container-fluid noPadding'>
    {{#if isInRole 'Admin'}}
      <h3 class="homepageText">Server Statistics</h3>
      {{> serverFacts}}
    {{else}}
      You don't belong here!
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
</div>
```

You'll need a helper to compute `loading` based on your subscriptions. In a more complicated layout backed by several subscriptions you might end up with more than one spinner spinning at a time.